# Screen is not scrolling Expo web

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-web

I have just updated to the latest expo sdk 33, So I can use the expo web capabilities. The project appears to be working and I can navigate onto different screens but I can scroll on any of the screens.
Does anyone have any idea what I might be doing wrong or missing?

Expo-cli version is : '2.19.5'

I'm using Yarn

**package.json**

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "latest",
    "expo": "next",
    "expo-cli": "^2.19.5",
    "expo-codemod": "^1.0.0",
    "expo-constants": "latest",
    "expo-image-manipulator": "latest",
    "expo-image-picker": "latest",
    "expo-intent-launcher": "latest",
    "expo-permissions": "latest",
    "firebase": "^5.8.1",
    "native-base": "^2.12.1",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-firebaseui": "^3.1.2",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-33.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-alert-async": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-modal": "^9.0.0",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^6.0.0",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^5.2.3",
    "react-native-web": "^0.11.4",
    "react-navigation": "^3.5.0-alpha.0",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
    "schedule": "0.4.0",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0",
    "prettier": "1.16.4"
  },
  "prettier": {
    "jsxBracketSameLine": true,
    "arrowParens": "always",
    "bracketSpacing": false
  },
  "private": true
}
```

**App.js**

```
    const AppContainer = createBrowserApp(AppNavigator);
    type Props = {};

export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));

    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <AppContainer
          onNavigationStateChange={(prevState, currentState) => {
            const currentScreen = getActiveRouteName(currentState);
            const prevScreen = getActiveRouteName(prevState);
          }}
          ref={(navigatorRef) => {
            NavigationService.setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef);
          }}
        />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: setting overflow-y: "scroll" in one of the divs in index.js fixes the scrolling problem, but I did that in inspect element, and Im trying to figure how to do it in my project permanently, but cant find the index.js without ejecting.

Comment: I am having the same problem. did you solve it ?

Comment: @pinturic I havent had a chance to look at  getting back to fixing this. I do have a link to tweet form Evan Bacon who works at Expo on the web section. https://twitter.com/Baconbrix/status/1139623120388538369

Comment: @pinturic did you get any solution yourself?

Comment: Wonderful I replied as well! Really I tried to fog into the code but was really hard to understand bin which part of the code that react object is allocated. The only thing I could understand was that it was in the React navigation code

Comment: Yeah, I’m not sure either. I’ll keep trying over the next couple of weeks

Comment: @pinturic Have you resolved this issue yet? I'm facing the exact same problem and what Evan Bacon proposed on that tweet didn't worked for me

Comment: @Jose Vf nope I did not try. What exactly have you tried?

Comment: _Set header mode to screen in the stack nav_ and _for createBrowserApp the second prop could be a string "hash"_

Comment: This happened to me. It boiled down to a `Flatlist` being contained in a `View`. Removing this wrapper `View` fixed the scrolling for me.

If you do encounter this issue, take a look at your View structure and adjust your styling (Add or remove wrappers, add or remove `flex: 1`, etc.)

Comment: Thanks very much, Ill take note of that in the future. Ive since started to move away from React Native & Expo and into just ReactJS where I'm going to make it a PWA instead.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this wrapping my main View with ScrollView

```
<ScrollView>
  <View>
  </View>
</ScrollView>
```